# Ломаются пути при подключении картинок, стилей, шрифтов в html, css файлах при билде через webpack

Tags: webpack

Пути любого вида превращаются в путь со слешом начале,  т.е, например, /img/1.jpg. И поэтому все пути не работают и в консоли вижу ошибку: "ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND", если заменить начало пути на ./, то все работает. Друзья! Прошу, помогите решить данную проблему.

```js
// index.js
import './index.html'
import './index.scss'
```

```js
// webpack.config.js
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    entry: ['./index.js'],
    output: {
        filename: '[hash].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        publicPath: '/',
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './index.html',
            minify: isProd,
        }),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new MiniCssExtrackPlugin({
            filename: '[hash].css'
        })
    ],
    devServer: {
        port: 3000,
        hot: isDev,
        historyApiFallback: true
    },
    optimization: optimization(),
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ['babel-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /.html$/,
                loader: 'html-loader',
                options: {
                    attributes: {
                      root: '.',
                    }
                }
            },

            {
                test: /.scss$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: MiniCssExtrackPlugin.loader,
                        options: {
                            hmr: isDev,
                            reloadAll: true,
                        },
                    },
                    'css-loader',
                    'sass-loader',
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: '[hash].[ext]',
                            outputPath: './img',
                            useRelativePath: true
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
                        options: {
                            mozjpeg: {
                                progressive: true,
                                quality: 75
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Начало пути ставится в зависимости от значения в publicPath конфигурации output у вебпака.

Если все ассеты у тебя будут на уровне baseUrl оставь слеш. Если они относительны текущей дирректории - укажи ./